# ViewModel creates 2 instances instead of 1

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I am currently implementing a one Activity application with multiple fragments using Google's NavGraph, at the moment i have a Fragment inside the MainActivity that holds a ViewPager2 and inside 2 child Fragments for the tabs

Right now i have 1 ViewModel that holds the parent and child Fragments, when i initialize the ViewModel, instead of creating a single instance for all 3 Fragments, i get 1 instance per Fragment, how do i have only 1 instance?

this is how i init the ViewModel for the parent and child Fragments

```
paymentViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(PaymentViewModel::class.java)
```

shouldn't the ViewModelProvider return the already created instance if it already exists instead of duplicating?

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the `context` passed in to the `ViewModelProvider`'s contructor, so essentialy currently you're getting the vm provider of the activity, which should return the instance the activity is using.

So yes, the snippet should work as I see, how are you instantiating the VM in the activity?

Comment: i am not instantiating the VM in the activity, only in the 3 fragments (the parent and 2 tabs), and they are all using the line above